# Glmnet: How to avoid glmnet from standardizing the factor/dummy variables?

Tags: categorical-data, glmnet

Having read this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136085/can-glmnet-logistic-regression-directly-handle-factor-categorical-variables-wi) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r), I already know that `model.matrix` can help convert data frame with factors into a design matrix.

My **question** is if you pass this `model.matrix` into `glmnet` or `cv.glmnet` function with the argument `standardize` set to `TRUE`, it still scales those dummy variable columns, am I correct ? So it means that `glmnet` still cannot differentiate the categorical variables from the continuous variables and handle them differently. So how can I make glmnet standardize the non-categorical columns but not the categorical columns ?

Comment: I think this is probably meant to be on SO... Anyway, the obvious thing would be to pass to `glmnet` a model matrix where only the variable you wish to be standardised are standardised and set the argument `standardize` to `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes but we are suppose  to standardise the validation set  when we train the model during cross validation . By setting 'standardise' to 'FALSE' , does it mean we are skipping this step in the 'cv.glmnet' function ? This standardization thing really bugs me.l because it makes me feel like I am implementing something that is not entirely correct .

Comment: I probably misinterpreter something...What would you train on a non-standardised set and then validate on a standardised one? You might use `caret` and define your own cross-validation procedure if you are bothered so you don't use `cv.glmnet` at all.